# Random jokes in a skit (activerecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, random

I am working on populating my database with test data using populate.rake:

```
Repertoire.includes(:jokes).each do |r|
  @jokes = r.jokes
  Skit.populate 8..12 do |skit|
    skit.joke_id = @jokes[rand(@jokes.count)].id
  end
end
```

This is giving me a RuntimeError: Called id for nil.

How can I populate a skit with random jokes?

Comment: How? One by one. I'll start: Inheritance is the object-oriented way to become wealthy.

Comment: I'll admit it... I just got lost in that programmer's joke question that appeared after I entered in this title o=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_by {rand}` should sort your array of jokes.

Or, there is also doing an `.order("rand()/random()")` (depending on your db) in your Repertoire query and putting a limit on the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem but Ruby has a `rand` method for arrays so you should be able to call `@jokes.rand.id` instead. Seems like that would simplify things and maybe even fix your error.